# Instantisation in Python

Tags: python-3.x, instantiation

I have just started learning to program in Python. I am finding it difficult to instance objects properly. It gives a traceback but I don't know why. I have been reading the documentation for 3.8 and still not sure what is causing the error? Your help is deeply appreciated.

Thank you.

````
    def _init_(self, name, age, character):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.character = character

    def date_of_birth():
        return 2020 - self.age



Breeds = Breeds = [Dog("Alsation", 2,["Protective","Smart"]), Dog("Rotteweiler", 3,["Possessive","Aggressive"]), Dog("Chihuahua",1,["Loud, Jumpy"])]

sum = 0
for dog in Breeds:
    sum = sum + Dog.age

print("The average age of breeds is: " + str(sum/len(Breeds)))'''


```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hilary\Desktop\hello.py", line 12, in <module>
    Breeds = Breeds = [Dog("Alsation", 2,["Protective","Smart"]), Dog("Rotteweiler", 3,["Possessive","Aggressive"]), Dog("Chihuahua",1,["Loud, Jumpy"])]
TypeError: Dog() takes no arguments
>>> ```
````

Comment: Dog() takes no arguments

This says that Dog Class doesn't accept any arguments.

Comment: Please search how to create objects with parameters in python. Secondly

Breeds = [Dog..   This assignment should be only once.

You are done assignment twice.

Comment: `'_init_' != '__init__'`

Comment: Not related to your original question, but your loop to sum all the dogs age should be changed from: `sum = sum + Dog.age` to `sum += dog.age`. When you call `Dog.age` you will get an `AttributeError` because the class `Dog` doesn't have the attribute `age` set, the instance of the class has.

Comment: @HampusLarsson when I do that it gives a different answer.  0.3333333 instead of 2.0.

Comment: @OverLord-in-Beta I have no way of knowing what code you're running now, because the code posted above gives all kinds of errors. If you cannot resolve the problem yourself, open a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__init__` method requires 2 underscores left and right, you are using 1.

Therefore your init method isn't recognized, and Python doesn't see any constructors that take your number of arguments.